# How to get the same property in all nested objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, tree

How can I get all the values of the property `code` in nested arrays of objects? I mean, no matter how many nesting levels.

```
[
  {code: '1', children: [
    {code: '11'}, {code: '12'}
  ]},
  {code: '2', children: [
    {code: '21'}, {code: '22', children: [{code: '221'}]}
  ]},
]
```

Expected result : `[1, 11, 12, 2, 21, 22, 221]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is your friend for this, and you can combine it with a recursive function, destructuring function parameters with [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_value), and array rest syntax.

```
const flatten = arr => arr.flatMap(
  ({ code, children=[] }) => [code, ...flatten(children)])
```

```js
const flatten = arr => arr.flatMap(
  ({ code, children=[] }) => [code, ...flatten(children)])


const arr = [
  { code: '1', children: [{ code: '11' }, { code: '12' }] },
  { code: '2', children: [{ code: '21' }, { code: '22', children: [{ code: '221' }] }],},
]

console.log(flatten(arr))
```

---

By the way, what you have there is a well-known data structure named [`tree`](https://medium.com/@iampika/javascript-trees-b8f3b4261c3a), you should research more about it, and specially the different ways to traverse them: [dfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [bfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Answer (score 1):

A good example for generator function and dfs or bfs

```js
const laziness = [{
    code: '1',
    children: [{
      code: '11'
    }, {
      code: '12'
    }]
  },
  {
    code: '2',
    children: [{
      code: '21'
    }, {
      code: '22',
      children: [{
        code: '221'
      }]
    }]
  },
]

console.log([...bfs(laziness)])
console.log([...dfs(laziness)])

// bfs
function* bfs(items) {
  const queue = [...items]
  while (queue.length) {
    const item = queue.shift()
    yield + item.code
    if (item.children) {
      queue.push(...item.children)
    }
  }
}

// dfs
function* dfs(items) {
  for (const item of items) {
    yield + item.code
    if (item.children) {
      yield* dfs(item.children)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using recursion and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) as:

```
function getCodes(arr) {
    return arr.flatMap((o) => {
        const childrenCodes = o.children ? getCodes(o.children) : [];
        return [+o.code, ...childrenCodes];
    });
}
```

```js
const arr = [
    { code: '1', children: [{ code: '11' }, { code: '12' }] },
    { code: '2', children: [{ code: '21' }, { code: '22', children: [{ code: '221' }] }],},
];

function getCodes(arr) {
    return arr.flatMap((o) => {
        const childrenCodes = o.children ? getCodes(o.children) : [];
        return [+o.code, ...childrenCodes];
    });
}

console.log(getCodes(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to make it work:

```
function getCode (nestedArray, current = []){
 nestedArray.forEach((e)=>{
  if ('code' in e) current.push(e.code)
  const keys = Object.keys(e);
  keys.forEach(k => {
   if (Array.isArray(e[k]) getCode(e[k], current);
 }
 return current;
}

getCode([
 {code: '1', children: [{code: '11'}, {code: '12'}]},
 {code: '2', children: [{code: '21'}, {code: '22', children: [{code: '221'}]}]},
])
```

Comment: a bit difficult for me but thank you for your help, sir

Comment: All solutions will require recursion or generators for what you need. Pick your flavor. This solution will cover you with any objects that there might be, no matter if they are under the ley children or any other. Other solutions might have their advantages too